# Firefox extension: label align left in menuitem

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

```
<menupopup>
    <menu label="label">
        <menupopup>
            <vbox flex="1">
                <menuitem>
                    <label value="test text" crop="left" />
                </menuitem>
            </vbox>
        </menupopup>
    </menu> 
</menupopup>
```

Result:

[image]

How to align left a label?

Comment: Why is there even a `<vbox>` in there?

Comment: Your code does not  (tested), and can not, produce the output you have in the question. Among other things, there is only one set of text `test text`, thus no list of 2 lines is possible. Further, there is no issue of alignment as you have specified no width for any item and thus the popup is fitted to the displayed text (a single line of `test text`).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah try taking out that `vbox` and setting `flex=1` on the `menupopup`, if that doesnt work than move the `flex=1` to the `menuitem` if still no then move it to the `label`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as to what you are attempting to accomplish:

1. `<menuitem>` elements usually have a left portion of the list which is reserved for either a check mark, or an icon image for the `<menuitem>`. Your use of the `<vbox>` element appears to be attempting to get around this. Adding the [`class="menuitem-non-iconic"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Style/menuitem-non-iconic) attribute is the normal method of doing this.
2. `<menupopup>` lists are auto-sized to the contents. Thus, in your code there is no issue of left or right alignment, as the popup is sized to the text.
3. `<menupopup>` elements are normally left aligned unless otherwise specified.
4. Your image could not have been produced with the code you provided.  The code you provided has only one `test text` label. Your image shows two.  Thus, it could not have been produced with the code you have provided.

Assuming that the gist of what you have provided is that you want a `<menupopup>` that contains a list of `<menuitem>` elements which are left or right aligned as you choose then the following will produce what you appear to desire:

```
<label value="Right click for popup" context="clipmenu" />
<menupopup id="clipmenu">
    <menu label="label">
        <menupopup width="300">
            <menuitem label="test text 1" crop="left" class="menuitem-non-iconic"/>
            <menuitem label="test text 2" crop="left" class="menuitem-non-iconic"/>
            <vbox flex="1">
                <menuitem>
                    <label value="test text 3" crop="left" />
                </menuitem>
                <menuitem>
                    <label value="test text 4" crop="left" />
                </menuitem>
            </vbox>
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
</menupopup>
```

This produces the following:
[image: Left aligned menupopup]

Note: I added a `width="300"` attribute to the inner `<menupopup>` element to illustrate left and right alignment.  I also added a couple of `<menuitem>` elements with the [`class="menuitem-non-iconic"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Style/menuitem-non-iconic) attribute which is the normal method of removing the space on the left for the checkmark rather than the `<vbox>` which you appear to be using to perform the same function.

Now if you wanted the text in the `<popupmenu>` right aligned instead of the default left aligned, you could change the line:

```
        <menupopup width="300">
```

to:

```
        <menupopup width="300" align="end">
```

Which results in:

[image: Right aligned menupopup]

The [`align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/align) attribute:

> The align attribute specifies how child elements of the box are
>   aligned, when the size of the box is larger than the total size of the
>   children.
>
> - For boxes that have horizontal orientation, it specifies how its    children will be aligned vertically.
> - For boxes that have vertical    orientation, it specifies how its children will be aligned    horizontally.

The [`pack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/pack) attribute:

> The pack attribute specifies where child elements of the [box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/box) are
>   placed when the box is larger that the size of the children. For boxes
>   with horizontal orientation, it is used to indicate the position of
>   children horizontally. For boxes with vertical orientation, it is used
>   to indicate the position of children vertically. The align attribute
>   is used to specify the position in the opposite direction.